# How to move an observation to the next row when certain conditions are present?

Tags: r, if-statement

Here is a representation of my dataset

```
ID<-rep(1,12)
Trimester<-c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,10)
SurgeryType<-c(c("A","B",NA,NA,NA,"C",NA,"A","C","B",NA,NA))


mydata<-data.frame(ID,Trimester,SurgeryType)
```

I have a number of patients followed on a trimestrial basis. I would like to have only one type of surgery per trimester. When one has two or more types of surgery in a single trimester, I would like to shift the second  surgery to later months, but only if it does not overlap with other surgery already present.

What I do firstly is to concatenate all surgeries of same trimester (for the same individual after grouping by ID) in string separated with hyphens, then took the `distinct` by `ID`, `trimester`.

```
mydata2<-mydata%>%group_by(ID,Trimester)%>%
  mutate(string=paste0(unique(SurgeryType),collapse = "-"))

mydata2<-mydata2%>%distinct(ID, Trimester,.keep_all=TRUE)
```

Thus I will have in the same row the different surgeries of the first and 7th trimester in string.

```
mydata2[mydata2$Trimester%in%c(1,7),]

     ID Trimester SurgeryType string
  <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>       <chr> 
1     1         1 A           A-B   
2     1         7 A           A-C
```

What I really want is when there is two element in a string (or two surgeries in a trimester) to move the second one in the following row, but only if this following row is empty (that is NA).

So I want to move the `surgery B` of the 1st trimester to the second trimester. But I can not move the second surgery `(C)` of the 7th trimester in 8th trimester as it is not empty. I let it as it is.

The returns of my datasets must be like this:

```
      ID Trimester SurgeryType string
   <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>       <chr> 
 1     1         1 A           A     
 2     1         2 NA          B     
 3     1         3 NA          NA    
 4     1         4 NA          NA    
 5     1         5 C           C     
 6     1         6 NA          NA    
 7     1         7 A           A-C   
 8     1         8 B           B     
 9     1         9 NA          NA    
10     1        10 NA          NA
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? what coding issue are you having a problem with?

Comment: I really have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, if this solution is very stable if used with real data. I tried to solve this one using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

mydata %>% 
  drop_na(SurgeryType) %>% 
  group_by(ID, Trimester) %>% 
  mutate(new_trim = Trimester + row_number() - 1,
         n = n(),
         m = row_number() - 1) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Trimester = ifelse(n > 1 & m > 0 & new_trim %in% mydata$Trimester, Trimester, new_trim)) %>% 
  select(-n, -m, -new_trim) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  right_join(mydata %>% select(-SurgeryType) %>% distinct(), by=c("ID", "Trimester")) %>% 
  arrange(ID, Trimester)
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 25 x 3
      ID Trimester SurgeryType
   <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>      
 1     1         0 A          
 2     1         1 B          
 3     1         2 NA         
 4     1         3 NA         
 5     1         4 C          
 6     1         5 NA         
 7     1         6 A          
 8     1         7 A          
 9     1         7 B          
10     1         8 NA         
11     1         9 NA         
12     1        10 NA         
13     2         0 NA         
14     2         1 NA         
15     2         2 A          
16     2         2 C          
17     2         3 A          
18     2         4 NA         
19     2         5 NA         
20     2         6 NA         
21     2         7 C          
22     2         7 B          
23     2         8 A          
24     2         9 NA         
25     2        10 NA
```

Comment: where did you create the ```df_temp``` ?

Comment: `df_temp` should be `mydata`.